# How to set a Background image to CCMenu in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am making a game which has a drop down menu in it. And so I want the menu to have a background image to it as it is transparent for now.

`//CCSMenu stethMenu 

    stethMenu->alignItemsInColumns(2,2,2); 

    stethMenu->setPosition(winsize.width/2,winsize.height/2);`

stethMenu is the Menu that I want to have a background. I have the background image in a CCSprite. I tried to make the sprite a child of stethMenu but that did not work gave an exception.

One method from the top of my head is to make the sprite a separate child of the current Layer and set its position to the same as menu. I was hoping for a better way of doing it, so that I do not have to set the position of sprite same as the menu every time its position changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider the method you thought about which is using a CCSprite as a child of the CCLayer as the solution the most faithful to cocos2d's design principles.

However, rather than adding the CCSprite and CCMenu as separate children of the CCLayer, I would suggest to add the CCMenu as a child of the CCSprite. Using this method you effectively only have to change the position of the CCSprite, and all its children will be positioned relative to it.

The node diagram would look like so:

- CCLayer

  - CCSprite

    - CCMenu

      - CCMenuItem
      - CCMenuItem
      - CCMenuItem
      - etc...

Comment: I have not tried that yet, but may be I will try it in the future apps.

Answer (score 0):

Create CCSprite and add it to parent of CCMenu, make z-order of background sprite less than CCMenu.

Comment: No not working, Assertion failed
dynamic cast CCMenu child!=0 something like that.

Comment: How come, I suggested you to add background(CCSprite) to base layer...(parent of CCMenu)..

Comment: Well that is not the answer then, I already knew that see in my question last paragraph...

Comment: what I do is, add menu to background and ccmenu position to ccp(0,0) always. And set position for MenuBtn items...that works even when u add ccmenu to any layer...Also once u move CCMenu then all btn moves...

Comment: yes that is correct. My menu has six items. In addition to these items I want the menu as a whole to have a background image.
Like the image in link below:
http://s24.postimg.org/doggraww5/stethoscope.png